# Sketching the Points in the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to sketch the points in the complex plane satisfying the given inequality:

$-\pi < \arg(z) < \pi/2$

If $\arg(z) = \pi/4$, what exactly is there to sketch?

Comment: To (almost) answer your specific question, a certain half-line. If it is not obvious which half-line, find a couple of points on it.

Comment: What is a half-line?

Comment: Take a full line, and a point $P$ on it. A half-line is the set of points on the line that are on one side of $P$, possibly including $P$.  Big further hint: The point $z=1+i$, which we can think of as $(1,1)$, has arg equal to $\pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

If you view $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $-pi<arg(z)<\frac{pi}{2}$ is the 2nd quadrant.

$arg(z) = \frac{pi}{4}$ is the ray originating from (0,0) and going towards $(\infty,\infty)$ i.e. following the line y=x in the first quadrant.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I will sketch that then.

Answer (score 0):

for $-\pi<\arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ you need to shade all the argand diagram **except** for the second quadrant where $\frac{\pi}{2}<\arg(z)<\pi$. Exclude the positive imaginary axis and the negative real axis.

$\arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is a **part line** equivalent to the line $y=x$ in the first quadrant only and excluding the origin.